# How many indices can be specified in a search call?

Tags: elasticsearch

As specified in the Elasticsearch [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html#multi-index), elasticsearch needs the indexes specified in the URL for the GET call. This limits the number of indexes one can query due to the limitation of the URL in a GET call.

Is there a way to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the indices inside the request body :

```
{
    "indices" : {
        "indices" : ["index1", "index2"],
        "query" : {
            "term" : { "tag" : "wow" }
        },
        "no_match_query" : "none"
    }
}
```

See [Indices Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-indices-query.html).